# Binding ListView to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem with binding `Listview` to my database using Entity Framwork.
This code only shows the first row of the table but the records do not show:

```
var item = (from p in db.tbl_film
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
string[] items = {item.flm_id.ToString(),item.flm_name,item.flm_description,item.flm_category };
foreach (var itemlist in items)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(items);
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

I have a table that has several records. Now I want to show it in the ListView.

Table: flm_film

Fields: flm_id, flm_name, flm_category

I want to see data with Entity Framework in ListView in details mode.

Comment: Has `string[] items` data ? How many ? Can you show me an example data ?

Comment: winforms list view binding tables mode view details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code :

```
var items = (from p in db.tbl_film select p).ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    // Create your ListViewItem here
    // Then add it to your listView here.
}
```

If you want to retrieve multiple records, you shouldn't have to use `FirstOrDefault()` because, as it says, you get only the first record.

Comment: have error when    ListviewItem listitem = new ListviewItem(item) ;

Comment: Of course you have an error, you have to manually create that ListViewItem.

Comment: Let one example ListviewItem thanks   >>> ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(?????);

Comment: You can do it by your-self using Google. Please refer MSDN or this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Please give us more informations about your film table if you want more help (edit your post).

Comment: ListViewItem newitem = new ListViewItem(item.SomeFieldName);