# connect ListView to database with entity framwok listview details mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have `tbl_film` with records :

```
flm_id ,
flm_name ,
flm_description ,
flm_link ,
```

I bind the `listview` to database records in order to show the `ColumnHeader`
Let your tips and code examples.

Mode : Details

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i want bind database to listview by entityframwork but i want Specific table from database show in listview by Specific columnHeaderText listview in details mode

Comment: He asked exactly the same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352111/binding-listview-to-database/18352957?noredirect=1#comment26945467_18352957